# How to work around limitation that a trigger's INSERTED and DELETED tables cannot use column/field of data type text

Tags: sql-server, text, triggers

I have read here and online that the special tables used by triggers, `INSERTED` and `DELETED`, cannot access columns that have the data type `TEXT`, `NTEXT`, or `IMAGE`. I know the first response will be to change the data type but this is a 3rd party database so I cannot do that.

It seems easy to grab the new data which is what `INSERTED` holds, but I do not see any way to get the data from the `DELETED` table.

Is there any way around this? I have looked online for workarounds and cannot find any. Does this mean it is not possible?

This needs to be done in an `AFTER` trigger that runs on `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE`. I cannot use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger because I cannot replace the DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE action being done to the table. I have to go with that action.

1. Added a computed column that applies to the `TEXT` column. The formula uses `CAST` to change to data type `varchar(max)`.
2. Added a computed column that applies to the `TEXT` column. The formula uses a custom scalar function to change to data type `varchar(max)`.

I have searched online and cannot find anything.

Comment: Then speak to your 3rd party. `text`, `ntext`, and `image` were all deprecated in SQL Server 2005 (*18 years ago*), they shouldn't be using them any more and should have updated their application to stop using it some time ago.

Comment: I would also ask if you really need a trigger. I find they are over used and most of the time another option is available which ends up being a better solution.

Comment: @ThomA, it's not possible. It's why I mentioned it. That's not a possible solution. I need another way. I specifically need to get the TEXT field from DELETED table into the trigger. Nothing else is applicable.

Comment: @seanlange, I would entertain another way but I am not sure. I need to cover different scenarios and a trigger is the easiest way (that I know of) to cover all of your bases. This way, it does not matter which source is changing the data, I get to grab it. There is a software (that cannot be altered) and there are other SQL objects, such as stored procs that I think are kicked off by SQL Agent. I know I could alter those stored procs to write the necessary data, but that does not cover when the software makes changes. I cannot alter the software so the database is my only choice.

Comment: To suggest an alternative solution is not possible with the info provided, however one option might be to implement system_versioning from where you can access the row as it was prior to the last update or delete.

Comment: It's not possible to speak to the 3rd party..? Why not? Do they not exist anymore? If so then perhaps you should try changing the data type in your dev environment and seeing what breaks, if anything. If the 3rd party doesn't exist anymore they aren't going to care what you do to the database. In truth, I've only encountered one application taty broke after changing one of those data types and that was with `image` (and was due to relying on implicit conversion, if I recall correctly, but this was *many* years ago).

Comment: To be brutally honest, there is nothing that `text` supports that `varchar(max)` doesn't etc, so I doubt 3rd party will even notice if you change it. Otherwise, just re-join `YourTable` by primary key to `inserted`.

Comment: If you create a log table that saves the current value as last step of your trigger, you can then access the last value from it for the "deleted" parts of your trigger code. Otherwise, it's not possible

Comment: @siggemannen, yeah, I think that is my only option. Thank you for confirming no other workaround exists.

Comment: Btw, i'm not sure why you cannot use instead of triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Just re-join the main table using the primary key.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER SomeTrigger ON SomeTable FOR INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT SomeOtherTable (value)
SELECT CAST(t.text_value AS varchar(max))
FROM inserted i
JOIN SomeTable t ON t.PK = i.PK;
```

Ideally you should change the column name. Almost nothing is supported by `text` and `ntext` that is not supported by the newer `max` types, so I doubt the application will even notice.